# T-SQL Right Joins to ALL Entries inc Selected Column

Tags: t-sql

I have the following Query which produces the output below;

```
SELECT
    TBLUSERS.USERID,
    TBLUSERS.ADusername,
    TBLACCESSLEVELS.ACCESSLEVELID,
    TBLACCESSLEVELS.AccessLevelName
FROM
    TBLACCESSLEVELS INNER JOIN 
    TBLACCESSRIGHTS ON TBLACCESSLEVELS.ACCESSLEVELID = TBLACCESSRIGHTS.ACCESSLEVELID INNER JOIN
    TBLUSERS ON TBLACCESSRIGHTS.USERID = TBLUSERS.USERID
```

The output is this;

```
29   administrator   1           AllUsers           
29   administrator   2   JobQueue                   
29   administrator   3   Telephone Directory Admin  
29   administrator   4   Jobqueueadmin              
29   administrator   5   UserAdmin                  
29   administrator   6   Product System             
27   alan            1   AllUsers                   
97   andy            1   AllUsers                   
26   barry           1   AllUsers                   
26   barry           2   JobQueue                   
26   barry           3   Telephone Directory Admin  
26   barry           4   Jobqueueadmin              
26   barry           5   UserAdmin                  
26   barry           6   Product System             
26   barry           7   Newseditor                 
26   barry           8   GreetingBoard
```

What I would like to do is modify the query so I get all Access Levels regardless of weather there is an entry for that user. What I would also like to do is some sort of exist case so that I get output like the following;

```
29    administrator   1       AllUsers                       True
29    administrator   2       JobQueue                       True
29    administrator   3       Telephone Directory Admin      True
29    administrator   4       Jobqueueadmin                  True
29    administrator   5       UserAdmin                      True
29    administrator   6       Product System                 True
29    administrator   7       Newseditor                     False
29    administrator   8       GreetingBoard                  False
27    alan            1       AllUsers                       True
27    alan            2       JobQueue                       False
27    alan            3       Telephone Directory Admin      False
27    alan            4       Jobqueueadmin                  False
27    alan            5       UserAdmin                      False
27    alan            6       Product System                 False
27    alan            7       Newseditor                     False
27    alan            8       GreetingBoard                  False
97    andy            1       AllUsers                       True
97    andy            2       JobQueue                       False
97    andy            3       Telephone Directory Admin      False
97    andy            4       Jobqueueadmin                  False
97    andy            5       UserAdmin                      False
97    andy            6       Product System                 False
97    andy            7       Newseditor                     False
97    andy            8       GreetingBoard                  False
26    Barry           1       AllUsers                       True
26    Barry           2       JobQueue                       True
26    Barry           3       Telephone Directory Admin      True
26    Barry           4       Jobqueueadmin                  True
26    Barry           5       UserAdmin                      True
26    Barry           6       Product System                 True
26    Barry           7       Newseditor                     True
26    Barry           8       GreetingBoard                  True
```

---

So the rules are ALWAYS show ALL Entries for ACCESSLEVELS and where EXISTS in ACCESSRIGHTS produce a true / false to show this.

I hope this makes sense and hopefully you dont need the table definitions as everything I need to work with is in the original Query. I just need a way of manipulating it slightly and getting the join in the right place.

Thank you.
Pace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.USERID,
        u.ADusername,
        al.ACCESSLEVELID,
        al.AccessLevelName,
        CASE WHEN ar.accesslevelid IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS Access
FROM    tblusers u
CROSS JOIN
        tblaccesslevels al
LEFT JOIN
        tblaccessrights ar
ON      ar.ACCESSLEVELID = al.ACCESSLEVELID
        AND ar.USERID = u.USERID
```